# Why time command in linux has different output when I type it in shell than I use it in script?

Tags: linux, bash, time

The problem is when I use time in shell I get output like that:

```
1.350u 0.038s 0:01.45 95.1%     0+0k 0+72io 1pf+0w
```

And when Im using it in script I get:

```
real    0m1.253s
user    0m1.143s
sys     0m0.047s
```

I mean why? And in shell script at the beginning I write:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash has a built-in command `time`, and your system should also have a separate binary at `/usr/bin/time`:

```
$ help time
time: time [-p] pipeline
    Report time consumed by pipeline's execution.

    Execute PIPELINE and print a summary of the real time, user CPU time,
    ...
$ which time
/usr/bin/time
```

The two commands produce different outputs:

```
$ time echo hi
hi

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ /usr/bin/time echo hi
hi
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+199minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: Yes you're right but why script is using different command than it's shell?

Comment: the /usr/bin/time binary is not in the path when running the script, but it is when you are in the shell. Or you are not running bash shell in the command line?

Comment: Now Im really confused. I echo'ed $SHELL and I got /bin/tcsh, but I still think its bash

Comment: Do a `type -a time` in Bash: It will show you everything executable that Bash knows of that is named `time`.  In my case, it says `time is a shell keyword` and `time is /usr/bin/time`.  I recommend that people prefer using `type` over `which` in Bash.  (We used to have problems years ago because `which` used the C shell, and not Bash, and since we didn't support C shell internally, its `$PATH` tended to be a system default and incorrect.)

Comment: Yes you're right it gives me:
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time

Comment: Also, if your script has `#!/bin/sh` as its shebang or none at all, it's likely going to be run using a shell other than Bash.

Comment: Another way to run the non-builtin `time` in sh-like shells (like Bash) is, instead of specifying a full path, use `\time` or `command time`.