# Using time in a bash script: how to get the "normal" output?

Tags: bash, shell, time

If I use `time` in the shell, I get an output like

```
$ time sleep 1

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

However, if I use the same command in a bash script, the output is this

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:01.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2176maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+179minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I already found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037171/why-time-command-in-linux-has-different-output-when-i-type-it-in-shell-than-i-use), but what I want is to use `time` in a script, while still getting the same output as if I was using it in a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the `-p` flag?

```
$ echo "time -p sleep 1" > x1

$ bash x1
real 1.01
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

Answer (score 3):

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:01.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2176maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+179minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

...is the default output produced by the GNU version of the external [`time` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time).

```
real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

...is the default output produced by the [`bash` builtin `time`](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html).  This builtin version of `time` is a `bash` extension: a [POSIX-compliant shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) is not required to provide a builtin version of `time`.

However, [POSIX does specify an external `time` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html), which can take `-p` option to produce yet another output format:

```
real 1.01
user 0.00
sys 0.00
```

...and the `bash` builtin also accepts the `-p` option to produce the same output format.

---

The `bash` builtin should work perfectly well in a shell script *provided the script is actually being run by `bash`*:

```
$ cat time.sh
#!/bin/bash
time sleep 1
$ ./time.sh

real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$
```

So it seems that your script is invoking the external utility rather than the `bash` builtin.

The most likely cause of this is that:

1. your script says `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`; and
2. the `/bin/sh` on your machine is not actually `bash`, but a more lightweight POSIX-compliant shell without the `bash` extensions (as found on some Linux distributions these days).

The solution is to ensure that the script specifically invokes `bash` by using `#!/bin/bash` if it relies on `bash` extensions.

Comment: As for the cause: 1. My script does say ``#!/bin/bash`` 2. I use Ubuntu which -- yes, you're right -- comes with the *dash* shell and not the *bash*.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that output is not going to terminal when piped.

The terminal codes necessary to do the nice layout do not work on a filestream.

What did you want to achieve? If you intend to have the 'screenshot' have a look at `script`

Comment: Formatting/terminal-codes is not the OP's issue ... if it was `time sleep 1 | cat` would also show the "other" format ... see the link in the post it has the correct WHY answer, but not how to work around